# How can dlerror() return NULL if dlopen() fails?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, shared-libraries

I am working on system that loads all `*.so` modules library automatically by call a script.

I tried to update one of the modules to support XML-RPC. I used the library `ibxmlrpc-c3-dev` on Ubuntu 10.10. The problem that `dlopen()` fails after my changes and `dlerror()` returns NULL. The compilation does not return any error.

How can I debug and fix this issue? Below is the code:

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#ifndef WIN32
#include "unistd.h"
#endif

#include "xmlrpc-c/base.h"
#include "xmlrpc-c/server.h"
#include "xmlrpc-c/server_abyss.h"

#include "config.h"  /* information about this build environment */
```

And, I added this function , most of the lines are commented out ,even though `dlopen()` fails:

```
int RPC_Server(int           const port) {

   // xmlrpc_server_abyss_parms serverparm;
    //xmlrpc_registry * registryP;
    xmlrpc_env env;



    xmlrpc_env_init(&env);

    //registryP = xmlrpc_registry_new(&env);

   // xmlrpc_registry_add_method(
    //    &env, registryP, NULL, "sample.add", &sample_add, NULL);

    /* In the modern form of the Abyss API, we supply parameters in memory
       like a normal API.  We select the modern form by setting
       config_file_name to NULL:
    */
  //  serverparm.config_file_name = NULint
    RPC_Server(int           const port) {

       // xmlrpc_server_abyss_parms serverparm;
        //xmlrpc_registry * registryP;
        xmlrpc_env env;



        xmlrpc_env_init(&env);

        //registryP = xmlrpc_registry_new(&env);

       // xmlrpc_registry_add_method(
        //    &env, registryP, NULL, "sample.add", &sample_add, NULL);

        /* In the modern form of the Abyss API, we supply parameters in memory
           like a normal API.  We select the modern form by setting
           config_file_name to NULL:
        */
      //  serverparm.config_file_name = NULL;
       // serverparm.registryP        = registryP;
       // serverparm.port_number      = port;
       // serverparm.log_file_name    = "/tmp/xmlrpc_log";

       // printf("Running XML-RPC server...\n");

       // xmlrpc_server_abyss(&env, &serverparm, XMLRPC_APSIZE(log_file_name));

        /* xmlrpc_server_abyss() never returns */

        return 0;
    }L;
   // serverparm.registryP        = registryP;
   // serverparm.port_number      = port;
   // serverparm.log_file_name    = "/tmp/xmlrpc_log";

   // printf("Running XML-RPC server...\n");

   // xmlrpc_server_abyss(&env, &serverparm, XMLRPC_APSIZE(log_file_name));

    /* xmlrpc_server_abyss() never returns */

    return 0;
}
```

and this is the code the is used to load modules

```
#ifndef RTLD_NOW

#define RTLD_NOW DL_LAZY
#endif   
void* handle;
char* error;


handle=dlopen(mod->binary_file, RTLD_NOW); 

if (!handle){
LOG( " could not open file [%s]: %s\n",
    mod_cfg->binary_file, dlerror() );
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The use of DLLs will not result in compilation errors; they are _dynamically_ linked libraries.

Comment: Indeed, more details may turn out to be helpful. Generally, I'd recommend to debug with `gdb` and fix with `vim`.

Comment: I only added inludes statments and one function , I commented out most of lines for testing , but dlopen still fails

Comment: Can you paste the code that calls `dlopen` and `dlerror`?

Comment: What is the argument to `dlopen`? (Is the path an absolute one, see `realpath` function)?

Comment: What is your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` ?

Comment: no It is not the absolute path, and I do not think this is the problem , since It is working if I remove my new function

Comment: What command line (flags) did you pass to the compiler when compilng the new module?

Comment: It is not a new module , It is part of existing module , I am trying to find the compilation script ,

Comment: How can I get the LD_LIBRARY_PATH ? sorry I am not linux user , I tried from terminal to use echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH , but it does not return any thing

Comment: Here the icludes that used in compilation includes :=    -I/usr/include/libxml2 `pkg-config glib-2.0  --cflags`                           ,should I add the path to xml-RPC package in compilation statement ?

Comment: If you found out what was the error, please tell us.... Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In this code:

```
handle=dlopen(mod->binary_file, RTLD_NOW); 

if (!handle) {
    LOG( " could not open file [%s]: %s\n",
         mod_cfg->binary_file, dlerror() );
```

the most likely way I can think of for the `dlerror()` to return `NULL` here is if `LOG` itself calls one of the `dl*` routines (which would clear the error state that `dlerror` returns).

So,

- show us what `LOG` macro (if indeed it *is* a macro) expands to, and
- run the program under GDB, set breakpoints on `dlopen`, `dlmopen`, `dlsym` and `dlvsym`, and observe that one of them is called *after* your call to `dlopen` above and before your call to `dlerror`.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a debugger like `gdb`.

If you cannot use it, try to use `strace` or `ltrace` on the process doing the `dlopen`

Also, clear `errno` before calling `dlopen` and display it (or print it under the debugger) just after the failing `dlopen`.

Check with `file`, `objdump`, and `nm -D` that your `dlopen`-ed `*.so` file has all the required properties (e.g. symbols).

Perhaps the memory address space of the process doing the `dlopen` is so full (or has reached some resource limits) that some internal `malloc` inside `libdl.so` fails (e.g. the one used by `dlerror`).

Answer (score 0):

```
handle=dlopen(mod->binary_file, RTLD_NOW); 

if (!handle){
string errmsg = string(dlerror());
LOG( " could not open file [%s]: %s\n",
    mod_cfg->binary_file, errmsg.c_str() );
return 0;
}
```

I come across the same problem when using BoostLog, and above is my solution.
I suppose LOG affects dlerror().

Comment: This is a duplicate of another answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with VirtualBox and Qt5 on an Ubuntu system; Qt5 couldn't dynamically load `libqxcb.so`, and after some debugging it turned out that both `dlopen()` and `dlerror()` were returning `NULL`.

The cause turned out to be because `VirtualBox` is a setuid binary and can't `dlopen` libraries in directories that aren't owned by root. In my case, the solution was as simple as running:

```
sudo chown root:root /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

My non-root user (with UID `1000`) owned `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` somehow, likely some error on my part. But after returning ownership to root, VirtualBox—and by extension Qt—could load libraries just fine.

I suspect this *may* have something to do with AppArmor, but I've no experience with it so I can't say for sure.

Answer (score -1):

Above all, you should definitely use `dlerror`.

Comment: but the original poster says that it returns NULL !

Comment: @jørgensen Just a ping to let you know the question was edited. The OP did note that `dlerror()` returned NULL, but has since been edited for clarity.